# Generator functions with next() call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I had a look on the new future from `ecmascript 6` - generator functions and I'm a bit confused about what `.next()` function does.

In the official documentation they say, and I quote : `A zero arguments function that returns an object with two properties:`, information updated on `Feb 17, 2015 4:57:46 PM` according to their [website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) ( `<-` link to documentation provided here )

So, let's say we have this generator function :

```
 function* first(){
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
 }
 var f= first();
```

When calling `f.next()` will return `{value:1, done:false}`. When you call it again will return `{value:2, done:true}`

BUT, if we have something like this:

```
function* second() {
  var a = yield "HELLO";
  console.log("a = ", a);

  var b = yield a+ 1;
  console.log("b = ", b);

  return b
}
var f= second();
```

When you call it like this: `f.next()` you'll receive `{value: "HELLO", done: false}`

Next call  will be `f.next(1)`, which will assign 1 to a, and it will output `{value: 2, done: false}`

Next call will be `f.next(1)`, which will output `{value: 1, done: true}`

**Questions**

1. How it's possible you can call `.next()` with parameter if in the official documentations it's stated it's a zero parameter function ?
2. Why at 3rd result has `value` property equal to 1  and at the second call it's equal to 2?
3. Why b is 1 and not 2 ?

Thank you !

```
PS: Of course, there's another usage of generator functions ( to avoid callbacks ), but I'm asking about this particular case.
```

Comment: While MDN is a good source for JavaScript, you can't really say it's the "official" documentation. Truly official is only the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: I didn't know. I've got a link to it from the guy above. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How it's possible you can call .next() with parameter if in the official documentations it's stated it's a zero parameter function ?

Quoting the [draft version of ES-6](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-iterator-interface),

> **Arguments may be passed to the `next` function but their interpretation and validity is dependent upon the target Iterator.** The `for-of` statement and other common users of Iterators do not pass any arguments, so Iterator objects that expect to be used in such a manner must be prepared to deal with being called with no arguments.

So, passing arguments to `next` doesn't violate the ES6 specifications. In this case, the value passed to `next` will be assigned to the variable you are assigning the `yield` expression to.

> 2. Why at 3rd result has value property equal to 1 and at the second call it's equal to 2?
> 3. Why b is 1 and not 2 ?

The list of operations in the order as they happen

1. **`f.next()`**

   ```
   yield "HELLO"
   ```

   So you are getting `{ value: 'HELLO', done: false }`
2. **`f.next(1)`**

   ```
   var a = 1;
   console.log("a = ", a);
   yield a + 1
   ```

   That is why you are getting `{ value: 2, done: false }` in this call.
3. **`f.next(1)`**

   ```
   var b = 1;
   console.log("b = ", b);
   return b
   ```

   That is why you are getting `{ value: 1, done: true }` here.

Comment: yea, but var b= yield a +1 ? Shouldn't it be 2 ?

Comment: @Kosmo I edited my answer a little bit, does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes ! Thank you ! I undestand the concept better now

Answer (score 1):

Use other values and it becomes much clearer. It's working as intended.

```
function* second() {
  var a = yield "HELLO";

  console.log("a = ", a);
  var b = yield a+ 1;

  console.log("b = ", b);
  return b
}
var f= second();

console.log('1:',f.next());
console.log('2:',f.next(5));
console.log('3:',f.next(7));
```

outputs

```
///1st next()
//yeld returns iterator
{value: "HELLO", done: false}

//2nd next(5)
//the console log gets executed with var a = 5
a = 5
//yeld returns iterator
{value: 6, done: false}

//3rd next(7)
//the console log gets executed with var b = 7
b = 7
//it doesn't use the 'a' var at all, neither does it add +1 to the yeld allocation
//yeld returns iterator
{value: 7, done: true}
```